# Unity Admob Mediation Test Suit Class Not Found

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, mobile-ad-mediation, googleads-mobile-unity

I am working on integrating Admob Mediation in our Unity Apps.
Though I can see the Ads but some AdNetworks are not integrated properly so I need to test them and for that Google has given it Admob Test Suit which I have downloaded (latest version) and imported into Unity Project but when I run it it is throwing following error

```
2018-12-10 12:43:15.818 32738-32759/? E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.unity.ads.mediationtestsuite.UnityMediationTestSuiteEventForwarder
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.unity.ads.mediationtestsuite.UnityMediationTestSuiteEventForwarder
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.unity.ads.mediationtestsuite.UnityMediationTestSuiteEventForwarder
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:
```

I haven't changed any thing just imported it as per documentation but I am not able to figure our why is it throwing this error and what could be its solution?

I am following following documentation

> https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation-test-suite

Hope to hear from you all soon.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference; You need to run the Play Service Resolver to add the necessary Android libraries. Unfortunately this is not stated in the official documentation as they must assume developers are using the "Auto Resolve" option.